# When does a custom User Property persist as a dimension for a User in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

We have setup a custom user property for our GA users, and are tracking that property with our GA events through GoogleTagManager.

I can confirm that user events are now coming through with the user property defined.
This user property will also be static for each user. So some User1 will always have their custom property value as "xyz", which will always be reported with each Google Analytics event.

I now want to be able to explore user data by using that custom user property as a dimension.
Now this is sort of working, I can see some percentage of users who are listed as "xyz" or "xyz2", etc...
But most of our users are still listed as (not set) for that user property, even though if I explore their user activity I can see that their events are coming through with the custom user property set as "xyz".

So my question is how does a dimension for a custom user property determine a users value for that particular custom property?
Do I have to wait for a majority of a user's events to have "xyz" for the custom property value before that user is moved to the "xyz" value of the dimension?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The user-level custom dimension is associated with the Google Analytics user and remains that until it is changed. Even if you no longer send the information of the custom dimension to that user, the last one sent to him will continue to be associated.

However if the sessions of the last few days have a "xyz" dimension and today you send the "xyz2" as value of that dimension, the user from now on will have "xyz2" but the sessions of the past days of that user (already frozen in Google Analytics) will always have "xyz", so that user will have 2 different values if you view the data in his entire period of activity.